# How to change bash default foreground color?

Tags: linux, terminal, colors, terminator

On my system, I've set my PS1 to end with a nice off-white.  But whenever I issue a command with color in the output, it will wind up calling the equivalent of `tput sgr0` and begin using the default prompt foreground color again.

[image: color problems]

How do I change the default foreground color of my terminal?  FYI the terminal emulator I'm using is terminator, and the shell is bash, though I don't think either of those things matter.

Comment: Can we see your PS1 prompt code?

Comment: Sure, but it won't help and it's massive.  What's going on in the image above is I'm leaving the fg color set to 230 (off white).  Then after the ls command prints the colored dot, it prints a control code that sets the color back to the default, something like `tput sgr0`.

Comment: My PS1 is a slightly modified version of this: https://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/3gu16u/whats_your_favourite_ps1_prompt/cu1m63h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, no, *both* of these things matter, though the terminal is more important, since that's where the default colors come from, and the method to change them varies.

For Terminator, it seems default foreground & background can be specified in its configuration, either under *Preferences → **Profiles***, or by editing `~/.config/terminator/config`:

```
[profiles]
[[default]]
foreground_color = "#FFFFFF"
```

Comment: I actually tried this before, but for some reason it wasn't working properly.  But now I got it.  Thanks!